# Integrate $\int \frac{dx}{(x^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ via trig substitution

Tags: integration, derivatives, trigonometry

$x = a\sec\theta, dx = \sec\theta \tan\theta$

$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ =
$ \int \frac{dx}{(\tan^2\theta)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ = 
$ \int \frac{dx}{\tan^{\frac{7}{2}}\theta}$ = 
$\int \frac{\sec\theta \tan\theta}{\tan\theta ^{\frac{7}{2}}}$ = 
$\int \tan^{\frac{-5}{2}}\theta \sec\theta$

Here is where I get stuck...I tried converting $\tan\theta$ and $\sec\theta$ in terms of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$, but that didn't seem to get me anywhere...What is my next move from here? Did I even start this problem correctly? I can't tell :(

---

Update with more work after initial answers:

$\int \frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}$ $u = \sin\theta, du = \cos\theta d\theta$

I found $\sin^{-1}\theta = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}$

$= \int \frac{du}{u^2} = \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{3}u^3} = 
\frac{1}{3\sin^3\theta}
= 3 \bigg( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} \bigg)^3$

Comment: In the denominator you added the exponents instead of multiplying them.

Comment: Why would I multiply them? I guess it is because it is an exponent of an exponent instead of an exponent * an exponent

Comment: You should **never** keep the differentials by changing the variable. You should do it **always** together. The problem starts from very beginning, where you use both $\theta$ and $dx$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}} =
 \int \frac{\tan\theta\sec\theta d\theta}{\underbrace{(\tan^2\theta)^{\frac{3}{2}}}_{\tan^3\theta}} = 
\int \frac{\sec\theta d\theta}{\tan^2\theta}= 
-\frac1{\sin \theta}=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}.$$

Comment: How do you get -$\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$? Please see my update

Comment: $$\int \frac{\sec\theta d\theta}{\tan^2\theta}=\int \frac{\cos\theta d\theta}{\sin^2\theta}=\int \frac{d\sin\theta}{\sin^2\theta}=-\frac1{\sin^2\theta}$$

Comment: I don't understand, what is the $d\sin\theta$ notation mean? It doesn't look like regular u-substitution?

Comment: For simplicity imagine that I introduced new variable $u=\sin\theta$.  Thus $$\int\frac{d\sin\theta}{\sin^2\theta}=\int\frac{du}{u^2}=-\frac1u=-\frac1{\sin\theta}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$(\tan^2 x)^{3/2}=\tan^3 x$$

Thus, yous should instead obtain
$$\int\frac1{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}dx
=\int\frac{\sec t\tan t}{\tan^3 t}dt
$$

which simplifies to
$$\int\frac{\cos t}{\sin^2 t}=\int\frac1{\sin ^2 t}d(\sin t)=-\frac1{\sin t}+C=-\csc t+C$$

Now reverse the substitution by the identity $\csc^2 t=\frac1{1-\cos^2 t}=\frac1{1-x^{-2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you do $x=\sec\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$ and $\mathrm dx=\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$, what you get is$$\int\frac{\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)}{\tan^3\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta=\int\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^3\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta=\int\frac{\cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{\bigl(1-\cos^2(\theta)\bigr)^2}\,\mathrm d\theta.$$Now, do $\cos\theta=u$ and $\sin\theta\,\mathrm d\theta=\mathrm du$.